# Connecting outlets in Window Based App, Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I'm reading through a beginners iPhone text book and just finished writing all the code for a route tracker app that uses Map Kit and Core Location. I have the app running with no errors on my iphone 4 device but when I tried interacting I realized that none of my IBOutlets were connected to anything. When I referenced the beginning of the tutorial in the text, all it says is to "connect the appropriate outlets".

Here's why this usually simple task has me confused. The tutorial says to create a Window Based Project, so there is no ViewController. Then, in Interface Builder, the view is built in MainWindow.xib. The only IBOutlets of the project are located in Controller.h / Controller.m files that you create and which contain mostly all of the code for the app.

I usually ctrl-drag from File's Owner to the UI in Interface Builder, but in this project there seems to be no way for me to access the IBOutlets in Controller.h / .m from the MainWindow.xib file.

I'm frustrated because it seems like this should be such an easy fix but I'm totally stumped.. any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have two choices:

1. Add the outlets to the app delegate.  This is probably not the best plan.
2. Put an instance of your controller class in the .xib file.

I think option 2 is what you want.  If you check the *Controllers* section of the library, you'll see a component called "Object".  Drag one of those into your xib, then inspect it.  Select the info pane in the inspector (the circle with a white `i` in it) and change the Class to the name of your controller class.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply to this answer and thank you for your help. After some searching I did find that the solution is choice #2.